# ASP.NET : How to Manage State in Class Library?

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-core-mvc, class-library

I have an ASP.NET MVC 6 application with a few class libraries (.NET 4.6.1). Now I want to pass the values between the asp.net application and the class libraries. For example I want to access UserId (that is inside a session) from the class library. I don't want to use parameters to pass the value, because UserId is a global variable in my class library and **I don't have a reference from web application in the class library**. What is the best way to solve this?

- Use Sessions in a class library?
- Use Shared Memory ?
- Use Web Service ?
- Use Dtabase ?
- ... ?

Update :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2040623/2455393 says that we can use this :

```
using System.Web;
var currentSession = HttpContext.Current.Session;
var myValue = currentSession["myKey"];
```

in .NET 4.6.1 (MVC 6) it does not work. but in .NET 4.0 it works well. this is my problem.

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040607/session-in-class-how-can-i-access or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930829/access-session-in-class-library?

Comment: `"I don't have a reference from web application in the class library"` - Then how is the application referencing that code in the first place?  It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do here.

Comment: This sounds to me like good use for ClaimsIdentity.

Comment: It's clear. The class library is not depends on the web application. But the web application used the class library. In .NET 4.0 I use HttpContext.Request.Session for accessing the shared data between two.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have a reference from web application in the class library.
>   What is the best way to solve this?

Ideally, class library should never have access to **HttpContext** *(unless it is related to presentation layer)*. Instead, you just pass **UserId** as a parameter to methods.

Otherwise, it will be hard to unit test the class library.

### How about Presentation Layer

If you want to access userId inside controller, you want to inject it, instead of accessing it from **HttpContext** directly.

For example,

```
public interface IUserSession
{
    int Id { get; }
    string FirstName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
    string UserName { get; }
    bool IsInRole(string roleName);
}

public interface IWebUserSession : IUserSession
{
    Uri RequestUri { get; }
    string HttpRequestMethod { get; }
}

public class UserSession : IWebUserSession
{
    public int Id => Convert.ToInt32(((ClaimsPrincipal) HttpContext.Current.User)?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid)?.Value);

    public string FirstName => ((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User)?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;

    public string LastName => ((ClaimsPrincipal) HttpContext.Current.User)?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value;

    public string UserName => ((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User)?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

    public bool IsInRole(string roleName) => HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(roleName);

    public Uri RequestUri => HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;

    public string HttpRequestMethod => HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod;
}
```

### Usage

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   private readonly IWebUserSession _webUserSession;

   public MyController(IWebUserSession webUserSession)
   {
      _webUserSession = webUserSession;
   }
}
```

Comment: It is using (ClaimsPrincipal) HttpContext.Current.User inside the class library. The problem is that HttpContext is null in the class library (in MVC 6)

Comment: As I said, using **HttpContext** inside class library is wrong. You want to leave it at **Presentation Layer**.

Comment: "As I said, using HttpContext inside class library is wrong" so what is the solution?

Comment: **you just pass UserId as a parameter to class library's methods**

Comment: in a web app we use sessions because we need a straight data over the app. consider we can use parameters instead. for the same reason I need to  access the sessions over the class library.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I could not recommend what you should do. If you follow [SOLID design principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), class library should not even know what front-end you are using. Ideally, you should be able to switch from Web Application to WPF without modifying a single line of code in class library.

Comment: I use the  library just for the web app. problem is clear, check if u can use httpcontext ( session) in a class library- .net 4.5. but it is safe and sound in. net 4.0